# How to fix eslint errors in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

```
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(attrs)) {
      element.setAttribute(`${key}`, `${value}`);
    }
  }
```

I am using this in my code which is used to select the key values of keyboard but some errors are shown by eslint

`error  iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations  no-restricted-syntax`

Comment: Try using `Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([key, value]) => element.setAttribute(key, value));`. eslint does not like `for...of` loops.

Answer (score 0):

As @dork correctly pointed out in his comment, (`eslint` suggests) you should not use `for ... of` loops. It is not supported in old browsers and may require a polyfill (`regenerator-runtime`).

Better write your code this way:

```
Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([key, value]) => element.setAttribute(key, value));
```

Comment: `setModalAttributes(element, attrs) {
    Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([key, value]) => element.setAttribute(key, value));
  }`

Comment: ** Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'setModalAttributes'** adding this to setmodalAttributes is not resolving the issue

Comment: Can you add the code that contains or calls `setModalAttributes()` to your question?

Comment: @KumarShivam it's because you didn't use `this` in the `setModalAttributes` function. Since it doesn't use `this`, you can move that outside and make it a utility function. Otherwise, just ignore the rule.